# Grid row double click performs action on main window

Tags: wpf, windows

This issue regarding WPF window (XAML application)
I have a two windows one window getting launced from another window. 
Both window get into maximized state when gets open
the child window which gets open has a grid on it and we have operation (double click on row click should close the window). 
Problem is happening that when we double click on grid row it closes form correctly but if accidently mouse remains in the same position then some operation on previous window gets perform. if mouse point in different location then there is no problem.
I am not able to define this as event bubbling in WPF or routed events.
Could you please advise on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add: 
`e.Handled = true`